# Master node in Hadoop cluster is crashed

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I am using 10 nodes cluster, Master node experienced hardware crash due to which all of the services including ambari server are inaccessible.

I am not able to access HDFS, neither I am able to login into ambari.

It is said that when Master ndoe goes down, SNAMEnode will be taking over, but in this case when master is not reachable none of the services are running it seems. Whole cluster is down, What is to be done further to save the cluster? Or it is the indication that I have to reinstall everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When namenode is down secondary namenode will not take role of namenode. Secondary namenode is used to perform checkpointing. Refer to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode for details . To have high availability of namenode you need to implement HA. Refer to [apache website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html) for more details.